# How can I make VS Code take me to the JS file instead of the .d.ts file on clicking an imported/required symbol or import/require path?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I want to reference a definition I press ctrl and left click on the variable, VSCode brings me to the definition. The problem is if a module has both `index.js` and `index.d.ts`, VS Code will bring me to the `index.d.ts` file which has no meaningful logic code. It's totally unusable to debug or to understand the implementation.

```js
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
var express = require('express')
```

For example, ctrl + left click on the `cookie-session` VSCode brings me to `./node_modules/@types/cookie-session/index.d.ts:115` instead of `./node_modules/cookie-session/index.js` where it shows:

```
declare module "cookie-session" {
    import express = require('express');

    function cookieSession(options?: CookieSessionInterfaces.CookieSessionOptions): express.RequestHandler;
    export = cookieSession;
}
```